# Python 3: my argparse method isn't working correct

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python 3, and my argparse method isn't working as it should. I already tried different examples from this website but nothing is working like I want it to.

My code looks like this:

```
import argparse

class CommandlineArguments():
    def __init__(self, number, duplicates, databases):
        self.number = args.number
        self.duplicates = args.duplicates
        self.databases = args.databases

    def ArgumentPassing(self):
        print('reached the variables')
        print(self.number * 2)
        print(self.duplicates)
        print(self.databases)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='TEST_LIST')
    parser.add_argument('-number')
    parser.add_argument('-duplicates')
    parser.add_argument('-databases')  
    args = parser.parse_args()

    commands = CommandlineArguments(args.number, args.duplicates, args.databases)
```

When I tried to run the program with:

```
python3 argparse_try.py
```

I was expecting that I would get a message like "too few arguments..." Instead, it just runs without any error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an argument to be required, you have to pass `required=True`.

Here's working code that requires all arguments. (I also changed your single dashes to double dashes, which is more typical, and I set `type=int` for `--number`, since I assume that's what you want.)

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='TEST_LIST')
    parser.add_argument('--number', required=True, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--duplicates', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--databases', required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

# Output if you don't pass any command-line options:
# usage: TEST_LIST [-h] --number NUMBER --duplicates DUPLICATES --databases
#                  DATABASES
# TEST_LIST: error: the following arguments are required: --number, --duplicates, --databases
```

**EDIT**

@Fujia makes a good point in their answer. You could make these positional arguments instead of options. This means you would use `python3 my_argparser.py 1 foo bar` instead of `python3 --number 1 --duplicates foo --databases bar`. To do that, use the following code:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='TEST_LIST')
    parser.add_argument('number', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('duplicates')
    parser.add_argument('databases')
    args = parser.parse_args()

# Output if you don't pass any command-line options:
# usage: TEST_LIST [-h] number duplicates databases
# TEST_LIST: error: the following arguments are required: number, duplicates, databases
```

**EDIT2**

Note also that this code is wrong:

```
def __init__(self, number, duplicates, databases):
    self.number = args.number
    self.duplicates = args.duplicates
    self.databases = args.databases
```

You presumably meant this:

```
def __init__(self, number, duplicates, databases):
    self.number = number
    self.duplicates = duplicates
    self.databases = databases
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your programme is that the argument names are prefixed with dash `-`.

If you just use `number`, `duplicates` and `databases` in `add_argument`, these three arguments become required. By default prefixing the argument name with dash or double dash will make them optional arguments during parsing. You can change this behavior by explicitly specifying the `required` parameter.